# How can I call this function from a button?

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I call this function from a button?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.destination is ViewController
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController
        vc?.city = self.city
    }
}
```

**New Issue:**

Why does the keyboard freeze when the wrong information is entered?

Here is the essential code that ties up the process being passed through the program.

**When return is pressed on the keyboard**

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchit()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}
```

**The function used inside the return**

```
func searchit() {


    city = searchBox.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)

}
```

**The segue that occurs when information is taken from the textfield**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.destination is ViewController
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController
        vc?.city = self.city
    }
}
```

**Function for receiving data from API and error**

```
func makeGetCall() {
    let jsonUrlString = "http://api.team.org/data/2.5/baseball?q=" + city + ",us"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return

    }
```

Comment: That's a segue action, you need to make the segue connect from a button to a view controller in your storyboard to make this function get called.

Comment: In the IBAction call [performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue)

Comment: Instead of a button how could I make the return key on the keyboard call it?

Comment: What would be the identifier for my segue?

Comment: Please read the linked documentation in my first comment.

Comment: Excellent! It now segues to the next controller, but if the wrong information is entered the keyboard freezes (cannot type or delete anything) any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Whoa, there! You **really** want to *edit* your question - not post a new one because your first wasn't that great. (And yes, you don't want to delete this question - even if I downvoted it.) The real bottom line is two-fold: First, let us help you. But second, let's help anyone else with the same problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "You don't". The system calls the `prepare(for:sender:)` method when you invoke a segue.

You can link a button directly to another view controller and set it up to trigger a segue, or you can call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` from your button's IBAction method. (If you control-drag from a button to a different scene in your storyboard Xcode will offer to attach a segue to the button for you. Otherwise you can wire up a normal IBAction method and call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` from the code for that IBAction.)

Once you trigger your segue, the system will call your `prepare(for:sender:)` so that you can pass any info you need to the segue destination.

As to the second question you asked in a comment: "...if the wrong information is entered the keyboard freezes (cannot type or delete anything) any idea why this is happening?" You should probably post a new question where you provide the code for your second view controller as well as a detailed description of what's supposed to happen and what goes wrong when "the wrong information" is entered. (We have no idea what information you are talking about, what makes some info wrong and some info correct, or how your code might get confused in the wrong info is entered.)

Comment: (When you ask a question, stop and think before posting. "Have I provided a clear description of my problem, with enough information so my readers understand what I'm trying to do, how I've set up my program, and what's going wrong?" If not, go back and add information until somebody who's reading your question has enough information to help you.

Comment: Got it! I’m fairly new to this..I’ve formulated a new question and will post it in about 60 (site restriction) I’ll keep you posted Thanks!

Comment: Whoa, there! You **really** want to *edit* your question - not post a new one because your first wasn't that great. (And yes, you don't want to delete this question - even if I downvoted it.) The real bottom line is two-fold: First, let us help you. But second, let's help anyone else with the same problem you're facing.(My problem? Been helping for two years and **still* have no clue how a space in a user name works here, so @Junior_Rickson, apologies for a double comment.)

Comment: Alright, I have updated the post..please have a look